# Why can't I assemble absolute addresses in the .text section on ARM64 MacOS?

Tags: macos, assembly, dynamic-linking, arm64, relocation

I'm writing in assembly using clang 13.1.6 with MacOS Monterey 12.5 on an ARM64 M1 Pro laptop.

If I try to use `.dword`/`.xword` in the `.text` section with the address of a label as its value, my program crashes on startup with a `bus error`.

Minimal reproducible example:

```asm
    .text
    .balign 4
    .global _main
_main:
    // accepted method to load from static address
    adrp x1, vector@GOTPAGE
    ldr x1, [x1, #vector@GOTPAGEOFF]
    // now x1 contains the address of vector
    ldr x2, [x1]
    // now x2 should contain the address of dest
    br x2
dest:
    mov x0, #0
    ret

vector: 
    .xword dest
```

This assembles and links without errors or warnings using `cc reloc.s -o reloc`, but bus errors immediately when run, apparently before even reaching my actual code.  The backtrace from `lldb` is as follows:

```
* thread #1, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x100003fb0)
    frame #0: 0x000000010001da54 dyld`invocation function for block in dyld4::Loader::applyFixupsGeneric(Diagnostics&, dyld4::RuntimeState&, dyld3::Array<void const*> const&, dyld3::Array<void const*> const&, bool, dyld3::Array<dyld4::Loader::MissingFlatLazySymbol> const&) const + 60
dyld`invocation function for block in dyld4::Loader::applyFixupsGeneric(Diagnostics&, dyld4::RuntimeState&, dyld3::Array<void const*> const&, dyld3::Array<void const*> const&, bool, dyld3::Array<dyld4::Loader::MissingFlatLazySymbol> const&) const:
->  0x10001da54 <+60>: str    x19, [x20]
    0x10001da58 <+64>: ldp    x29, x30, [sp, #0x20]
    0x10001da5c <+68>: ldp    x20, x19, [sp, #0x10]
    0x10001da60 <+72>: add    sp, sp, #0x30
Target 0: (a.out) stopped.
(lldb) bt
* thread #1, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x100003fb0)
  * frame #0: 0x000000010001da54 dyld`invocation function for block in dyld4::Loader::applyFixupsGeneric(Diagnostics&, dyld4::RuntimeState&, dyld3::Array<void const*> const&, dyld3::Array<void const*> const&, bool, dyld3::Array<dyld4::Loader::MissingFlatLazySymbol> const&) const + 60
    frame #1: 0x0000000100040fd4 dyld`invocation function for block in dyld3::MachOLoaded::fixupAllChainedFixups(Diagnostics&, dyld_chained_starts_in_image const*, unsigned long, dyld3::Array<void const*>, void (void*, void*) block_pointer) const + 424
    frame #2: 0x0000000100041080 dyld`dyld3::MachOLoaded::walkChain(Diagnostics&, dyld3::MachOLoaded::ChainedFixupPointerOnDisk*, unsigned short, bool, unsigned int, void (dyld3::MachOLoaded::ChainedFixupPointerOnDisk*, bool&) block_pointer) const + 104
    frame #3: 0x00000001000412b0 dyld`dyld3::MachOLoaded::forEachFixupInSegmentChains(Diagnostics&, dyld_chained_starts_in_segment const*, bool, void (dyld3::MachOLoaded::ChainedFixupPointerOnDisk*, dyld_chained_starts_in_segment const*, bool&) block_pointer) const + 208
    frame #4: 0x0000000100040e04 dyld`dyld3::MachOLoaded::forEachFixupInAllChains(Diagnostics&, dyld_chained_starts_in_image const*, bool, void (dyld3::MachOLoaded::ChainedFixupPointerOnDisk*, dyld_chained_starts_in_segment const*, bool&) block_pointer) const + 96
    frame #5: 0x0000000100040d98 dyld`dyld3::MachOLoaded::fixupAllChainedFixups(Diagnostics&, dyld_chained_starts_in_image const*, unsigned long, dyld3::Array<void const*>, void (void*, void*) block_pointer) const + 120
    frame #6: 0x000000010001da0c dyld`invocation function for block in dyld4::Loader::applyFixupsGeneric(Diagnostics&, dyld4::RuntimeState&, dyld3::Array<void const*> const&, dyld3::Array<void const*> const&, bool, dyld3::Array<dyld4::Loader::MissingFlatLazySymbol> const&) const + 136
    frame #7: 0x000000010001d788 dyld`dyld4::Loader::applyFixupsGeneric(Diagnostics&, dyld4::RuntimeState&, dyld3::Array<void const*> const&, dyld3::Array<void const*> const&, bool, dyld3::Array<dyld4::Loader::MissingFlatLazySymbol> const&) const + 204
    frame #8: 0x0000000100021574 dyld`dyld4::JustInTimeLoader::applyFixups(Diagnostics&, dyld4::RuntimeState&, dyld4::DyldCacheDataConstLazyScopedWriter&, bool) const + 604
    frame #9: 0x000000010000d904 dyld`dyld4::prepare(dyld4::APIs&, dyld3::MachOAnalyzer const*) + 1928
    frame #10: 0x000000010000d06c dyld`start + 488
```

The crash appears to be inside the dynamic linker, not in my code at all.

An even simpler example with the same behavior is:

```asm
    .text
    .balign 4
    .global _main
_main:  
    ldr x1, =dest
    br x1
dest:   
    mov x0, #0
    ret
```

Here `ldr x1, =dest` is supposed to similarly assemble the address of `dest` into the literal pool (a nearby location within the `.text` section) and load from there into `x1`.  This also bus errors.

Equivalent code works fine on ARM64 Linux.

Why is this, and how do I fix it?

Comment: This is a self-answered question to share the result of a very confusing experience.

Answer (score 8):

Absolute addresses in the text section seem to be unsupported by ARM64 MacOS.  As best I can tell, the dynamic linker tries to apply a relocation/fixup to store the actual runtime address of `dest` into `vector`, but crashes because `.text` is already mapped read-only.

So if you have an object that needs to be initialized with the address of a label or other object, then you need to put it in a data section, even if it is read-only.  This is what clang does when compiling C/C++ code.  For instance, if you write in C

```c
const int i = 42;
const int * const ptr1 = &i;
const int * const ptr2 = NULL;
const int * const ptr3 = (const int *)0xdeadbeefcafed00dUL;
```

then `i, ptr2, ptr3` all get preceded by `.section __TEXT,__const`, but `ptr1` is preceded by `.section __DATA,__const`.  The latter section is also read-only at runtime, but apparently is mapped read-write while relocation is done.

And you simply cannot use `ldr x1, =label` at all.  Use instead `adr` or `adrp / add` as appropriate to generate the address in `x1` if `label` is in the text section, or otherwise load it from the global offset table as appropriate.

It would be nice if the linker would detect this and warn you, instead of going ahead and building an executable that mysteriously crashes.