# Why use adr and ldr x2, =var to get the address of a variable?

Tags: assembly, memory-address, arm64

```
.data
varA: .quad 25
.text
.global main
//main function
main:
    adr x0,varA
    ldr x1, [x0]
    ldr x2,=varA
    ldr x3,[x2]
```

Will x0 and x2 same? Just memory access difference here as i learnt.

but why we need to again assign it to same or different register using [] to assign value? Isnt adr did it first line of main code?

Comment: You don't need to assign it again.  That looks like two separate examples of different ways to do the same thing.  (Except that `adr x1, [x1]` isn't valid, and you put the address in x0 not x1 with the first instruction.  So x1 still holds garbage.  Maybe you mean `ldr x1, [x0]`).  Of course if you did `ldr x0, [x0]`, that would overwrite the address so you wouldn't still have it for another load or store.  So don't do that if you want to make multiple accesses to the same variable.  Look at how compilers do it: https://godbolt.org/z/brKxPKc44 [and this Q&A](//stackoverflow.com/q/38552116)

Comment: after adr its same ldr. I mistakenly written here adr

Comment: Now that your example can build and run, you could single-step it in a debugger to confirm that `x0` and `x2` are still set.  They will be.

Comment: x0,x1 is it same? Or i just fill the same value to another register?

Comment: x0 and x1 are different registers.  No idea what you're asking.  If you put an address in x0, that doesn't also put it in x1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`adr reg, label` and `ldr reg, =label` will both, in principle, place the address of `label` in the register `reg`.  So the code in your question will result in `x0, x2` both containing the address of `varA`, and `x1, x3` both containing the value 25.

However, they work differently under the hood, which is good to understand because it leads to certain restrictions and tradeoffs for each approach.

- `adr reg, label` will assemble into the instruction the displacement between the instruction's own address and the address of `label`.  At runtime, it adds this displacement to the value of `pc` and places the result in `reg`, like `add reg, pc, #(label - .)` if such an instruction existed.  This has the advantage of being position-independent; if the entire binary is loaded at an arbitrary address in memory, then the same machine code still works, so long as the `.text` and `.data` sections remain at the same *relative* positions.

  The limitation is that the instruction only has space to encode a 19-bit displacement, so if your program is so large that the label and the instruction are more than 1 MB away from each other in either direction, the program will not link.  You can increase this to 4 GB by using a two-instruction sequence of `adrp` and `add`, see [Understanding ARM relocation (example: str x0, [tmp, #:lo12:zbi_paddr])](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64838776/understanding-arm-relocation-example-str-x0-tmp-lo12zbi-paddr/64841097#64841097).
- `ldr reg, =label` will assemble the absolute address of `label` into some nearby location in memory (called a literal pool), and emit a load instruction to fetch the address from there.  Equivalent to:

  ```
  ldr reg, literal_pool
  ...
  literal_pool:
  .quad label
  ```

  where `ldr reg, literal_pool` is a "literal load": the displacement between its own address and that of `literal_pool` is encoded in the instruction, and at runtime it adds the displacement to `pc`, then loads from the resulting address.  The displacement has to be less than 1 MB, but the assembler can usually arrange to put a literal pool within that range.

  The upside is that, in principle, it works without restrictions on the relative position of `label`, which can be anywhere in the 64-bit address space.  The downside is that extra memory is needed: besides the 4 bytes of the `ldr reg, literal_pool` instruction itself, an additional 8 bytes are needed for the absolute address of `label` in the literal pool.

  Also, as you can see from the above, `ldr reg, =label` is not position-independent, since it requires the *absolute* address of `label` to go in the literal pool.  If the code ends up being loaded at a different address than the linker assumed, such as for [address space layout randomization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization), then the stored address of `label` will have to be updated when the program is loaded, before it is executed.  In some cases the operating system will do this for you automatically (e.g. on Linux) but it does make the loading of your program take a few extra cycles, and the necessary metadata will make your binary a little larger.  Other operating systems just don't support this, e.g. MacOS ([Why can't I assemble absolute addresses in the .text section on ARM64 MacOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73382860/why-cant-i-assemble-absolute-addresses-in-the-text-section-on-arm64-macos)), in which case `ldr reg, =label` is simply not usable.  And if you are running on bare metal instead of under an existing OS, you would have to write extra code in your loader to do this relocation.

  As a result, although `ldr reg, =label` might seem like the simplest approach, it is not the most efficient or portable.  Compilers normally use the `adrp/add` combination mentioned above, which provides a position-independent solution that also works in quite large programs.

Comment: Wow.thanks for writing most clearing concept about my problem

Answer (score -1):

I finally understood the concept.

x0,x2 just hold the address
then we assign the value to x1,x3 from the address.